# How do I append a suffix to ids in a HTML file using standard unix commands?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

Assume I have an HTML file like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="a">
       content of div a
       <div id="b"> content of div b </div>
       <div id="c"> content of div c </div>
    </div>
    <style>
      #a {color: red; }
      #b {color: green; }
      #c {color: blue; }
    </style>
</body>
```

I want to append a unique suffix (say, `-suffix`) to all ids, which would include attributes `id="..."` and selectors `#...`, and result in a file like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="a-suffix">
       content of div a
       <div id="b-suffix"> content of div b </div>
       <div id="c-suffix"> content of div c </div>
    </div>
    <style>
      #a-suffix {color: red; }
      #b-suffix {color: green; }
      #c-suffix {color: blue; }
    </style>
</body>
```

How do I accomplish this with standard unix shell tools like `sed`, `grep`, `awk` in a way that would cover as many situations as possible?

**My attempt:**

I came up with the following `sed` command:

```
sed -e 's/id="\([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*\)"/id="\1-suffix"/g;s/#\([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*\)/#\1-suffix/g' index.html
```

Which is actually two commands in one:

- `s/id="\([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*\)"/id="\1-suffix"/g` - substitutes id attributes `id="..."`
- `s/#\(\[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*\)/#\1-suffix/g` - substitutes id selectors `#...`

However it's far from perfect. First, it only supports double attribute values in double quotes `id="..."` and id values are limited in that they have to match `[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*`. Second, this clashes with hex colors, so a white color like `#ffffff` would get a suffix `#ffffff-suffix`; An id selector like `#...` should only get a suffix if an appropriate attribute `id="..."` exists.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I suggest to use xmlstarlet.

Comment: To avoid the clash with hex colors you could try matching a the beginning of line, some space and then the id.  `s/^[ \t]*#\([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*\)/#\1-suffix/g`.  (Beware: I haven't tested this regex.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of cases in your file, as you mentionned with the colour problem
My approach would be to treat the file line by line using

```
cat inputfile.html | while read a; do
some code
echo "$a" >> outputfile.html
done
```

This being said, you may use

```
b=$(expr "$a" : "regex")
```

To precisely filter what you want to modify and only then, use some

```
sed
```

on $b to get what you want and push $b into $a